# Writing simple JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hello everyone I'm new to JQuery so I wanted to know if I can avoid repeats in my code. I have a very simple plugin here :

```
  $.fn.preview = function() {
      $(this).on("click", function() {
          $("body").append("<div class='c'><img></div>");
          $(".c img").css("max-height", $(window).height() - 20);
          $(".c img").css("max-width", $(window).width() - 20);
          $(".c img").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
          $(".c").css("display", "flex");
          $(window).on("click resize", function(e) {
              if ($(e.target).is(".c")) {
                  $(".c").remove();
              }
              $(".c img").css({
                  "max-height": $(window).height() - 20,
                  "max-width": $(window).width() - 20
              });
          });
      });
  }
  $("img").preview();
```

But here the code `$(".c img").css("max-height",$(window).height()-20); $(".c img").css("max-width",$(window).width()-20);` repeats two times. Is there any way to write it once?

Thank you very much for spending your precious time with my issue.

Thank you for any help!

```js
$.fn.preview=function(){
 $(this).on("click",function(){
  $("body").append("<div class='c'><img></div>");
  $(".c img").css("max-height",$(window).height()-20);
  $(".c img").css("max-width",$(window).width()-20);
  $(".c img").attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
  $(".c").css("display","flex");
  $(window).on("click resize",function(e){
   if($(e.target).is(".c")){
    $(".c").remove();
   }
   $(".c img").css({"max-height":$(window).height()-20,"max-width":$(window).width()-20});
  });
 });
}
$("img").preview();
```

```css
.c{display:none;justify-content:center;align-items:center;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8)}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/Wallpaper-4K.jpg" width="200"/>
```

Comment: For future reference: http://api.jquery.com/css. I'd also suggest you look in to providing a separate CSS stylesheet with your plugin and calling `addClass()`/`removeClass()`instead of using `css()` as it ties the styling and logic together too tightly.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do it like this!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare multiple CSS rules by passing an object as the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function parameter:

```
$(".c img").css({
    "max-height": $(window).height()-20,
    "max-width": $(window).width()-20
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this but my problem is that I need to run this function on image click and on window resize

Comment: If you really don't want to write it twice (which is fine in this case), wrap it in a function, and simply call this function instead.

Comment: Sounds great, yeah, well, it's really will shorten the code, thank you!